# Left join on a varchar column

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I know this is probably something stupid on my part, but please bear with me. I have basically 3 tables (let's simplify things):

**users**
user_id | account_id | phone | name | ...

**accounts**
account_id | name | ...

**phonedetails**
phone | country_code | ...

Let's pretend we have a simple query like this:

```
SELECT u.*, a.* FROM users u
LEFT JOIN accounts a ON a.account_id = u.account_id
ORDER BY u.user_id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This correctly assesses that the query needs to use eq_ref on account_id and properly selects only 100 records and is almost instant. However, when I want to do this (*this is a simplified version of what I want to use*):

```
SELECT u.*, p.* FROM users u
LEFT JOIN phonedetails p ON p.phone = u.phone
ORDER BY u.user_id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

It suddenly tries to go through Full Table Scan (so it's about 300 000 records at the moment) and then does its job. Sure, it works, but it takes almost 4 seconds for whatever reason!

account_id => type int in both tables (users, accounts)
phone => varchar(24) in both tables (users, phonedetails)

It doesn't seem to matter if I have an index on that column or not.
Funny thing is that if I do something like this:

```
SELECT u.*, (SELECT p.country_code FROM phonedetails p WHERE p.phone = u.phone)
FROM users u
ORDER BY u.user_id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

It correctly joins the tables using eq_ref and it's fast.

Is there something I can do to improve on the query performance?

**Edit with more info**:

Interesting (at least for me), is that if I execute this query:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
LEFT JOIN phonedetails p ON p.phone = u.phone
ORDER BY u.user_id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Explain shows those tables are joined correctly with eq_ref on the primary key and it's fast again. Of course, it's useless for me as I don't get the columns I need.

Comment: Is phone in the phonedetails table indexed?

Comment: @JonathanFite, yes, in the users table. In phonedetails table it's a Primary Key.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT u.*, p.* FROM (SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 100) u
LEFT JOIN phonedetails p ON p.phone = u.phone
ORDER BY u.user_id DESC
LIMIT 100 ;`

Comment: Can you share out put of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table name>` for all three tables?

Comment: Do you *need* all columns from `phonedetails`? Because it sounds like maybe it's doing a full table scan because it knows it needs all the phone columns. Is the primary key clustered?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  It sounds like `phone` is declared differently, possibly a different `CHARACTER SET`.

Comment: @RickJames, I've already verified this few times, columns have the same type, length and collation. It's just weird. If I do the join while users are joined to a different table (let's call it C), it's nicely fast.. If I just join users<->phonedetails, it's slow. There must be something fishy going on. I'd love to share more details, but I'm bound by my contract to not disclose any more data. Is there something else to try except index (done that) or verifying columns are the same? Can something else interfere with the join causing full table scan?

Comment: If you could fabricate a test case that avoids contract issues, either you would discover the problem in the process, and/or we could better help you, and/or you could have a test case ready to supply in a bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: Are you using InnoDB?

Comment: Can you get an "Optimizer Trace"?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  After providing my Answer, I got to wondering if it involves a relatively recent Optimization.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll stop trying to figure out why your query is not working and give you a technique for solving it...

```
SELECT  u.*, p.*
    FROM  
       ( SELECT  user_id   -- minimal data (just PK in this case)
            FROM  users
            ORDER BY  user_id
            LIMIT  100    -- now in subquery
        ) AS x
    JOIN  users AS u  ON u.user_id = x.user_id
    JOIN  phonedetails AS p  ON p.phone = u.phone
    ORDER BY  x.user_id   -- yes, need extra ORDER BY
```

The general principle:  When doing a `LIMIT` or `GROUP BY` and the query is even somewhat complex, it *may* be better to build a subquery that identifies which rows as simply as possible.  Then do the `JOIN`, etc, to get the rest of the data.

1. The subquery (called a "derived" table in this syntax) finds the user_ids -- and only the 100 needed.  Since you are doing `LEFT`, there is no need to involve `phonedetails` in this query.
2. Then reach out to the other tables to get the desired columns.

Caveat:  This version of the query may be slow for the same yet-to-be-discovered reason.  This reformulation *is* effective in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.  Explain was showing the ref as null with type of index, despite the column being my primary key.  I noticed a collation difference.  Once I made the collations match explain would return a type or eq_ref and ref of the joined field.  Leaving this here in case anyone else runs across this hunting down similar issue to check the collations.